# android deeplinking - the first path prefix is dynamic, but the second not

Tags: android, manifest, deep-linking, intentfilter

I have a url, e.g. [https://www.mobilePhoneSystem.com/{user}/registerDate/{date}](https://www.mobilePhoneSystem.com/%7Buser%7D/registerDate/%7Bdate%7D). So the `{user}` path-prefix is dynamic. I need to handle ONLY the deeplinks, that contains `registerDate`.
I wrote in my manifest something like this

```
<!-- Deep linking-->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="/www.mobilePhoneSystem.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/registerDate" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But it doesn't trigger. When I add any user in mainfest, e.g. `pathPrefix=/user111/registerDate`, it triggers and works fine. But the user is dynamic. So how can I handle this type of deeplink?

Comment: what would be the assetlinks.json file? No needs to add componants / path parameters there, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you :

```
android:pathPattern="/.*/registerDate/.*/"
```

**Explanation**
: The . enforces a pattern of "one of any character". The .* enforces "any number (or none!) of any character".

Combining these two, ..* enforces "any number of any characters, but at least one must be provided"

Comment: android:pathPattern="..*/registerDate/..*" - For me this solution worked with 2 dots, I didn't try with single dot, but anyway I'll accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check navGraphs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link)

in navGraph

```
<deepLink
    android:id="@+id/deepLink"
    app:uri="mobilePhoneSystem.com/{userId}/registerDate" />
       
<argument
    android:name="userId"
    app:argType="string"/>
```

Comment: That's the navigation component?

Comment: What if I'm not using navigation component?

Answer (score 1):

you could use library it will solve the problem for you [github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch](http://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch)
and you could even get your {user} and {date} directly without any added hassle